# UIButtons ,which are dynamic, not changeing its background image properly as per selected button's tag.

Tags: iphone

-(void)setButtons_AsPerTheMatrixSelection

{

```
    int x = 7;
    int y = 60;

    for (int j = 0; j <= 35; ++j)
    {
        if (j <= 5)
            btnMatrix = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
        else if (j > 5  && j <= 11)
            btnMatrix = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x-306, y+51, width, height)];
        else if (j > 11  && j <= 17)
            btnMatrix = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x-612, y+102, width, height)];
        else if (j > 17  && j <= 23)
            btnMatrix = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x-918, y+153, width, height)];
        else if (j > 23  && j <= 29)    
            btnMatrix = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x-1224, y+204, width, height)];
        else if (j > 29  && j <= 35)
            btnMatrix = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x-1530, y+255, width, height)];

        btnMatrix.tag = j;
        [btnMatrix setBackgroundImage:imgDefaultBG forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnMatrix.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
        [btnMatrix addTarget:self action:@selector(changeImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [viewWithButtons addSubview:btnMatrix];
        [self.view addSubview:viewWithButtons];

        x = x + 51;
        y = y;
        [arrButton addObject:btnMatrix];
    }
```

}

This is my code to add dynamic buttons as per the matrix of 6*6

here i am adding the button tag also,

Now i am going to click on button & would like to change background image with this code...

-(void)changeImage:(id)sender

{

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"No.png"];

UIButton *tmpButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:btnMatrix.tag];

NSLog(@"btn.tag is... %d",tmpButton.tag);


[btnMatrix setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

}

When i click to any button it always changing image of last tagged button...

i have to change Background of the selected button itself.

how can it be possible.

Please guide me i am not getting a part where i am doing a mistake.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)changeImage:(UIButton*)sender  
{
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"No.png"];
    [sender setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

BTW, your code is too messy, you may do like this

```
int pw = 306;
int ph = 51;

int ch = 6;
int cv = 6;

for ( int i = 0 ; i < cv ; ++i )
{
    for ( int j = 0 ; j < ch ; ++j )
    {
        UIButton *btnMatrix = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7+pw*j, 51+ph*i, width, height)] autorelease];
        btnMatrix.tag = i*ch+j;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am now able to change the image of every selected buttons as per the selected...But in the last line (means last row of 6 buttons) i am not able to change image.

Comment: does it print the log?  may the event did not fired, may be the buttons is out of the parent view

Comment: for (intimg = 1; intimg <= 14; intimg++)
{
 arr_FirstSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_f_1.png",intimg], nil];
}

Comment: In this code application is getting crashed at the time of executing this line of code "NSString *strImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_f_1.png",[arr_FirstSet objectAtIndex:i]];"

-(void)changeImage:(id)sender
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= [arr_FirstSet count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *strImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_f_1.png",[arr_FirstSet objectAtIndex:i]];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:strImage];
        [sender setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }    
}

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Answer (score 1):

Try this change in this method:

```
-(void)changeImage:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *Btnmatrix = (UIButton *)sender
   UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"No.png"];
   [Btnmatrix setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your function

```
-(void)setButtons_AsPerTheMatrixSelection
```

make your button local as follow

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 35; ++j)
{
    if (j <= 5){
    UIButton   *btnMatrix = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
      btnMatrix.tag = j;
    [btnMatrix setBackgroundImage:imgDefaultBG forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnMatrix.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
    [btnMatrix addTarget:self action:@selector(changeImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [viewWithButtons addSubview:btnMatrix];
}

// and so on every button

}
```

Hope this will help you. sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like `btnMatrix` is an ivar, and since you assign it successively to each button as you add them, it will hold a reference to your last button after you are done creating buttons. Change your line to inspect the `sender` object instead:

```
UIButton *tmpButton = (UIButton*)sender.tag;
```